# Appfuse with Tapestry 4

Tags: java, tapestry, appfuse

I want ask about appfuse. 
I want create an appfuse project with tapestry 4. but when i look at appfuse website, it only support tapestry 5 and not tapestry 4 anymore.

How or where can i find a appfuse with tapestry 4 skeleton project

Any help appreciated

many Thank's b4

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can still do that. Here's a very simple way how:

- Get Apache Maven 2 and have add in your to your Env (M2_HOME and Path)
- Get **archy** (http://code.google.com/p/archy/)
- Run it: `java -jar archy-0.1.jar`
- Enter the Maven archetype id: `appfuse-basic-tapestry`
- Enter your artifactId and groupId as instructed

Done!

Besides, you can still access and download older appfuse versions from their SVN repository. Take a look [here](http://java.net/projects/appfuse/sources/svn/show/tags) (you may need java.net login).